# Different colors for multiple data series with stem plot - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, colors, plot

```
x1 = 0:1:10;
x2 = 0.5:1:10;

X = [x1, x2];
Y = [(1/1.4).^x1, (2).^(-x2)];
stem(X,Y, 'filled', 'r')
```

What i want to do is to have the two series with different color.
How can i achieve that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
x1 = linspace(0,10,11)';
x2 = linspace(0.5,10,11)';

X = [x1, x2];
Y = [(1/1.4).^x1, (2).^(-x2)];
h=stem(X,Y, 'filled');
set(h(1),'Color','r')
set(h(2),'Color','k')
```

Comment: What if i wanted to specifically give the two series different color, say red and blue, and not just the colors given automatically??

Comment: EDIT: I still want the second series to lie in between the first one over the whole intervall. Im such a noobie!

Comment: For the first question : I made some modifications, by using the handle to the figure object you can easily set the color of each curve. Sorry, but I didn't understand the second question